# How many points can be placed in a many dimensional space at a specific cosine distance away from each other?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

Imagine I have a `n` dimensional vector space, and I pick a random unit length vector inside of this space, I now want to continue adding unit length / norm vectors so that they are always `x` cosine distance away from each other.

I would like to write a formula to calculate how many such vectors I can fit in the `n` dimensional space.

I view this as a form of quantisation of the continuous vector space.

EDIT: due to being asked for more information.

I am not sure what more to add to the above information, so I will try and explain it in another manner - say we have a 3d space, which is essentially a sphere of radius `1`. I insert a single vector of unit length into this sphere and now I keep adding vectors so that they are always `x` apart in terms of cosine distance - I would like know how many such vectors can fit into the sphere, but in reality I would like to know how this works in higher dimensions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Really? I am not sure what to add, can you please add information about why it is unclear?

Comment: @Community I have tried to explain it again - please let me know if this is better. Ideally however you could specifically let me know what is unclear.